# InProc vs StateServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

We recently changed from using `InProc` to `StateServer` for storing Session information.

I was wondering, if it's possible to update configuration files on the website now without losing session information. As when we used InProc and updated resource files (like language files), web config files, global.asax or files in the `App_Code`, we found that sessions appeared to reset and received errors like

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Does this change with going to `StateServer`? Is it safe to update these types of files without losing the session data? I have run a couple of tests on our test system, and it appears that it works OK, but I'm not 100% confident...

Comment: AFAIK, session objects should survive an apppool recycle using a state server.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace? It can be easier to say what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple answer to your query is **YES**

**Further more saying...**
 - Using State Server, session is serialized and stored in memory in a separate process (aspnet_state.exe).
 - State Server can run on another machine.
 - Session is persistent, you don't need to be afraid that your session data is lost during application restarts
 - When storing data of basic types (e.g. string, integer, etc), in one test environment it's 15% slower than InProc.
 - The cost of serialization/deserialization can affect performance if you're storing lots of objects.
 - Solve the session state loss problem in InProc mode. Allows a webfarm to store ASP.NET session on a central server. Single point of failure at the State Server.

**For more refer:**
  - [Steps for session inproc mode to state server](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2009/06/steps-for-session-inproc-mode-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Once your session data are out-of-process it's safe to restart worker processes. You can test it by logging in to your site, making some actions that involve session update and killing the corresponding w3wp.exe process (assuming it's IIS 7+) from the task manager (or just touching web.config).

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. I'm a newbie so just wanted a confirmation from more experienced peoples :)